# If $A$ and $B$ are arbitrary $n \times n$ matrices, prove that $(A^TB^TBA)$ is symmetric

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetry

My attempt:

$(A^TB^TBA)^T$=$(A^T)^T(B^T)^TB^TA^T$=$(AB)B^TA^T$ $\ne$  $(A^TB^TBA)$ therefore $(A^TB^TBA)$  is not symmetric.

Comment: I just edited the question. The original question was written incorrectly.

Comment: If $(A^TB^TBA)$ is symmetric, so is its transpose - you didn't change the question ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As what @AlexR mentioned, we have
$$(\underbrace{A^T}_{(1)}\,
\underbrace{B^T}_{(2)}\,
\underbrace{B}_{(3)}\,
\underbrace{A}_{(4)})^T=
\underbrace{A^T}_{(4)}\,
\underbrace{B^T}_{(3)}\,
\underbrace{B^{TT}}_{(2)}\,
\underbrace{A^{TT}}_{(1)}=A^TB^TBA,$$
and therefore $A^TB^TBA$ is symmetric.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $(AB)^T = B^TA^T$, unlike you assumed. With this in mind, redo what you did and you'll succeed.

Comment: I'm not sure what matrix $A$ and $B$ are in this problem. Could I get a hint?

Comment: @Debun $A$ and $B$ are any two matrices (compatible such that the product $AB$ is defined, of course). In your case all you need in addition to that is distributivity in this fashion: $(ABC)^T = ((AB)C)^T = C^T(AB)^T = C^TB^TA^T$

Comment: how would you use the distributive property for the transpose of i elements? i.e. $(k_1,k_2,k_3....k_i)^T$? Where $k_i$ is a matrix

Comment: @Debun If you think a little about it, you may get the idea that always singling out a lone term $(K_1 \cdots K_{n-1})K_n$ will help you turn the $n$ factor-Problem into a $n-1$ factor-Problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant answers but I consider it a fun exercise even though it can be laborious for some. 
Remember that the multiplication of two matrices $B=(B_{ij})_{\displaystyle^{1\leq i\leq n}_{1\leq j\leq n}}$ and $A=(A_{ij})_{\displaystyle^{1\leq i\leq n}_{1\leq j\leq n}}$ is outer matrix given by
$$
B\cdot A
=
(B_{ij})_{\displaystyle^{1\leq i\leq n}_{1\leq j\leq n}}
\cdot 
(A_{ij})_{\displaystyle^{1\leq i\leq n}_{1\leq j\leq n}}
=
\left(
\sum_{\alpha=1}^{n}B_{i\alpha}A_{\alpha j}
\right)_{\displaystyle^{1\leq i\leq n}_{1\leq j\leq n}}
\quad ( \ast )
$$
And with the same notation the transpose of $A$ and $B$ are given by
$$
(A_{ij})^{\;T}_{\displaystyle^{1\leq i\leq n}_{1\leq j\leq n}}=(A_{ji})_{\displaystyle_{1\leq i\leq n}^{1\leq j\leq n}}
\text{ and }
(B_{ij})^{\;T}_{\displaystyle^{1\leq i\leq n}_{1\leq j\leq n}}=(B_{ji})_{\displaystyle_{1\leq i\leq n}^{1\leq j\leq n}}
\quad ( \ast \ast)
$$
*i.e.* the permutation of the columns index $j$ with the index $i$ of the lines does not change the value of the entries of the matrix. And further note that,
$$
A^T\cdot B^T
=
(A_{ji})_{\displaystyle_{1\leq i\leq n}^{1\leq j\leq n}}\cdot (B_{ji})_{\displaystyle_{1\leq i\leq n}^{1\leq j\leq n}}
=
\left(
\sum_{\beta=1}^{n}A_{j\beta}B_{\beta i}
\right)_{\displaystyle_{1\leq i\leq n}^{1\leq j\leq n}}
\quad ( \ast\ast\ast )
$$
Now substituting $( \ast ), \; ( \ast\ast )$ and $(\ast\ast\ast)$ in $A^TB^TA\;B$ we have
\begin{align}
A^TB^TB\;A
=&
(A_{ij})_{\displaystyle_{1\leq i\leq n}^{1\leq j\leq n}}^T
(B_{ij})_{\displaystyle_{1\leq i\leq n}^{1\leq j\leq n}}^T 
(B_{ij})_{\displaystyle_{1\leq i\leq n}^{1\leq j\leq n}}
(A_{ij})_{\displaystyle_{1\leq i\leq n}^{1\leq j\leq n}}
\\
=&
(A_{ji})_{\displaystyle_{1\leq j\leq n}^{1\leq i\leq n}}
(B_{ji})_{\displaystyle_{1\leq j\leq n}^{1\leq i\leq n}}
(B_{ij})_{\displaystyle_{1\leq i\leq n}^{1\leq j\leq n}}
(A_{ij})_{\displaystyle_{1\leq i\leq n}^{1\leq j\leq n}}
\\
=&
\left(
\color{red}{\sum_{\beta=1}^{n}A_{j\beta}B_{\beta i}}
\right)_{\displaystyle_{1\leq i\leq n}^{1\leq j\leq n}}
\left(
\color{blue}{\sum_{\alpha=1}^{n}B_{i\alpha}A_{\alpha j}}
\right)_{\displaystyle^{1\leq i\leq n}_{1\leq j\leq n}}
\\
=&
\left(
\sum_{\gamma=1}^{n}
\Big(
\color{red}{\sum_{\beta=1}^{n}A_{\color{black}{j}\beta}B_{\beta \color{black}{\gamma}}}
\Big)
\Big(
\color{blue}{\sum_{\alpha=1}^{n}B_{\color{black}{\gamma} \alpha}A_{\alpha \color{black}{j}}}
\Big)
\right)_{\displaystyle_{1\leq j\leq n}^{1\leq j\leq n}}
\end{align}
Now it's easy to see that
$$
\left(
\sum_{\gamma=1}^{n}
\Big(
\color{red}{\sum_{\beta=1}^{n}A_{\color{black}{j}\beta}B_{\beta \color{black}{\gamma}}}
\Big)
\Big(
\color{blue}{\sum_{\alpha=1}^{n}B_{\color{black}{\gamma} \alpha}A_{\alpha \color{black}{j}}}
\Big)
\right)^{T}_{\displaystyle_{1\leq j\leq n}^{1\leq j\leq n}}
=
\left(
\sum_{\gamma=1}^{n}
\Big(
\color{red}{\sum_{\beta=1}^{n}A_{\color{black}{j}\beta}B_{\beta \color{black}{\gamma}}}
\Big)
\Big(
\color{blue}{\sum_{\alpha=1}^{n}B_{\color{black}{\gamma} \alpha}A_{\alpha \color{black}{j}}}
\Big)
\right)_{\displaystyle_{1\leq j\leq n}^{1\leq j\leq n}}
$$